# how to move jpa repository initialization from start up to session creation time for multi-tenant environment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, multi-tenant

I am integrating Jpa repository with my project that has multi-tenant support. So whenever a request comes in we set a tenant id in thread local like this -

```
public class AccessFilter implements Filter{
 @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
//
UserContext userContext = (UserContext) session.getAttribute(USER_CONTEXT);
TenantContext.set(userContext.getTenantId());

//
}
}
```

my jpa config goes like this

```
`<jpa:repositories base-package="com.adnan" factory-class="com.spmsoftware.appframework.repository.MyRepositoryFactoryBean"`  />
```

When I deploy start scanning packages and try to inject entity manager and transaction manager into JpaRepositoryFactoryBean but since AccessFilter didn't call yet (as it will be called when session is created), no tenant Id is set in thread local and it fails. My EntityManagerFactory code is like this -

```
@Override
    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return threadLocalHasFactory.get();
    }
```

I have gone through http://codecrafters.blogspot.sk/2013/03/multi-tenant-cloud-applications-with.html but this guy uses  Apache Shiro framework that in my case is not used.
What I m not sure is, how to move whole jpa repository creation logic from start up time to when session gets created.
I am using Hibernate4 with Spring 3.
Let me know if anyone needs more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and may be it is work sharing here.

I have removed autowiring of my repository class and started injecting it through AoP while method call. So i created around proxy of my method and here is the code that is written to set repository interface proxy in my service layer. For the below class you need to do some configuration so that it can be called around your service.

```
public class RepositoryCapableInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor, ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     *
     * @param methodInvocation method invocation passed by Spring
     * @return return value of target method.
     * @throws Throwable
     */
   @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        Object currentObj = methodInvocation.getThis();
        List<Field> toInitializeFields = fetchAllOptymyzeRepositoryChildes(currentObj);
        if (! toInitializeFields.isEmpty()) {
            RepositoryFactorySupport factory = applicationContext.getBean(RepositoryCreator.class).getRepositoryFactorySupport();
            for (Field f : toInitializeFields) {
                Object bean = factory.getRepository(f.getType());
                f.set(currentObj, bean);
                f.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }
        return methodInvocation.proceed();
    }

    private List<Field> fetchAllOptymyzeRepositoryChildes(Object currentObj) throws IllegalAccessException {
        List<Field> toInitializeFields = newArrayList();
        for (Field field : currentObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(OptymyzeRepository.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())){
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.get(currentObj) == null){
                    toInitializeFields.add(field);
                } else {
                    field.setAccessible(false);
                }
            }
        }
        return toInitializeFields;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
```

I hope it helps.